# Ihave Forgot my Admin Password. How to recover or reset

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database

I have registered azure database and have been using for some time.
But please I have forgot my Azure admin password, how do i reset. I cant login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just go to your sql server on azure portal and click the "Reset password" button.

[image]